# Visual Basic - Buttons Don't Activate Code?

Tags: vb.net

I have been having loads of problems making a simple VB program for work but finally go the code working and then the solution files got corrupted so I had to start again. Fortunately I had a lot of the code saved in a txt file!

I have recreated the form and added the code as below behind it, but when I hit either of the buttons, nothing happens? However, when I use the checkbox to keep the window uppermost, it works.

I can confirm that the buttons are named GoBut and ButNew and the Text box is called TextCode within the form design and that the second form is called NewDesign.

Please help, I hope it's something stupid and simple that I have missed!

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub chkTopmost_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As  _
       System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkTopmost.CheckedChanged
    Me.TopMost = chkTopmost.Checked
End Sub

Private Sub GoBut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim wdcode As String
    wdcode = TextCode.Text

    Dim wd_wild As String
    wd_wild = "*"

    Dim wd_full As String
    wd_full = wd_wild & wdcode

    Dim found As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, wd_full).FirstOrDefault()

    MsgBox(wd_full, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Found Directory")

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", found))
End Sub
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button

Private Sub ButNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    NewDesign.Show()
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Your handler is missing: `Handles GoBut.Click` at the end of this line: `Private Sub GoBut_Click...`

Comment: Also, your handler for `ButNew` is declared with `Button1`.  Your `With events` statement is also attached to `Button1`, is that supposed to be with `ButNew`?

Comment: Private Sub GoBut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoBut.Click

Comment: Private Sub ButNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButNew.Click

Comment: seems to have fixed those problems, I am a relative novice if you hadn't guessed! Not sure what this line is for?     Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button

Comment: The IDE usually write that code for you when you double click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Handler to your method. The result is :

```
Private Sub GoBut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoBut.Click

    Dim wdcode As String
    wdcode = TextCode.Text

    Dim wd_wild As String
    wd_wild = "*"

    Dim wd_full As String
    wd_full = wd_wild & wdcode

    Dim found As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, wd_full).FirstOrDefault()

    MsgBox(wd_full, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Found Directory")

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", found))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Drarig29's answer is spot on... If on the other hand you wish to add and remove handlers at run time (and you probably don't - you would need a good reason to do that), you should look at the AddHandler and RemoveHandler statements.

As for your question in the comments:

```
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

This is declaring a button, with support for events (not much point having one without!), that is visible to other code in the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

These are great answers. Also, keep in mind that if you create a button and set the handles clauses for it; it's best not to rename it or try to create a new button and name it the same thing as the old one. The program usually won't know that you mean for it to run that handling code for that button if it isn't the original button or has had the name changed. Always best to get your design set in stone before creating events unless you create them from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

As noted the Handles clause is missing. Two clues to problem areas: One, your new event as a '1' after the name e.g.Form1_Load. Two, place your cursor in-between subs and open the dropdown for the methods/properties top right. You will see a bunch of subs that used to be events. You can add the appropriate Handles... or copy the code into the new empty event subs.